# Easylist: Vertical Spacing

Tags: easylist

Using `easylist`, how do I set up vertical spacing between various "levels"? (Page 8 in the manual seems to be the appropriate section for this question but I am still confused.) For example, the vertical spacing between a level 1 entry and another level 1 entry; the vertical spacing between level 1 entry and level 2 entry; the vertical spacing between level 2 entry and level 2 entry; the vertical spacing between level 2 entry and level 3 entry; the vertical spacing between level 3 entry and level 3 entry.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hang=true,Margin=-3pc, Align=3pc, Indent=1em)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{easylist}
@ Level 1, item 1

@ Level 1, item 2

@@ Level 2, item 3

@@ Level 3, item 4

@ Level 1, item 5

@@ Level 2, item 6

@@@ Level 3, item 7

@@@ Level 3, item 8

@@ Level 2, item 9

@ Level 1, item 10
\end{easylist}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference regarding Page 8 of the [`easylist` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/easylist/easylist-doc.pdf) is quite detailed. Perhaps the following illustration would help:

```
...             |    ...
Level n item    |    Level !=n item
Spacen*         |    Spacen
Level n item    |    Level n item
...             |    ...
```

For example, `Space1` sets the vertical spacing before a first level item if the preceding item is from a level *other than* level 1; the starred version `Space1*` sets the vertical spacing before a 1st level item if the preceding item is from the *same* level. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hang=true,Margin=-3pc, Align=3pc, Indent=1em)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{easylist}
\ListProperties(Space1=0.75cm, % Level not 1, Space1,  Level 1
                Space1*=0.25cm,% Level 1,     Space1*, Level 1
                Space2=1cm,    % Level not 2, Space2,  Level 2
                Space2*=0.5cm, % Level 2,     Space2*, Level 2
                Space3=0.33cm, % Level not 3, Space3,  Level 3
                Space3*=0.1cm, % Level 3,     Space3*, Level 3
                )
@ Level 1, item 1

@ Level 1, item 2

@@ Level 2, item 3

%@@ Level 3, item 4
@@ Level 2, item 4

@ Level 1, item 5

@@ Level 2, item 6

@@@ Level 3, item 7

@@@ Level 3, item 8

@@ Level 2, item 9

@ Level 1, item 10
\end{easylist}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image: item spacing]

---

Due to the implementation of `easylist`, in particular the following code found in [`easylist.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/easylist/easylist.sty)

```
\expandafter\ifnum\el@PreviousItem=\el@CounterLevel
    \vskip\csname Space\the\el@CounterLevel*\endcsname
\else
    \vskip\csname Space\the\el@CounterLevel\endcsname
\fi
```

we see that: If previous and current items are at the same level, then `Spacen*` is used; otherwise, `Spacen` is used.

To define vertical space between Level 3 and Level 2, you can only do so by specifying `Space2`. To define vertical space between Level 3 and Level 1, you can only do so by specifying `Space1`. The point is: Think vertical space *before* the current item, not *after*.

Comment: Is it possible to define vertical spacing, say, between Level 3 and Level 2, and, Level 3 and Level 1? (Actually, this was the whole point of the original question but I forgot to mention it.)

Comment: @blackened Yes, you can, by specifying `Space2` and `Space1`, respectively. But I think you are still thinking about vertical space added *after* the current item. The package adds vertical space *before* items. Please check my added discussions.